# C# process shortcut key after child controls

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keyboard-shortcuts

I have shortcut keys in my **WinForms** application, but I want to process them **AFTER** the child controls.

I'm using KeyDown event in the main control and the 'g' key is used to display a grid. 
But in the edit box within the main control, when I press the 'g' key, the grid is displayed and the edit box receives the 'g'.
If I set the 'g' key handled by the shortcut, the edit box does not receive the 'g' key.

=> my goal is to have all the keys handled first by the children and then by the main window, if it's not been handled yet.

Here is a code snippet:

```
public ShortCutManager(Control Control, string Title)
{
    _Control = Control;
    _Control.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
}

private void OnKeyDown(object Sender, KeyEventArgs KeyEventArgs)
{               
    if (KeyEventArgs.KeyCode == Keys.G)
    {
        // What I need
        SendKeyEventToChildren(KeyEventArgs);

        if (KeyEventArgs.Handled == false)
        {
            DoShortcutCommand();
            KeyEventArgs.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What technology do you use (WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, Silverlight, etc)? Tag a question with corresponding tag.

Answer (score 1):

What I'm doing is to override the [`ProcessDialogKey` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processdialogkey.aspx) in my form, similar to how it is described in [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300977/arrow-key-events-not-arriving):

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    // Example: Handle Ctrl+C.
    if ((keyData & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control && (keyData & Keys.C) == Keys.C)
    {
        // Do some processing here...

        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
```

Comment: This implies that I implement the shortcuts in the control and not in a generic external class like it is now.

Comment: How about simply passing the `keyData` to your shortcut manager instance?

Comment: Ok, I've made a test and it does not work. When a key is entered, it is called 2 times (Key up & Key down) and when I call  base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData) it's always false when I press the G key, even if I'm in a edit box. Moreover, " This method is called during message preprocessing to handle dialog characters, such as TAB, RETURN, ESC, and arrow keys". So It won't return any answer for "regular" keys.

Comment: There is also [`IsInputKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey.aspx) which might help to count additional keys as dialog keys.

Comment: IsInputKey is called by some of the controls (like TextBox), and it is not called in the main form, I can't use it.