# Disable selection of buttons by enterkey in vb

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, arrow-keys

I have designed a calculator. Basically I have a label, and some buttons which includes btn0........ btn9, etc, btnequals. Now When i click on btn0...btn1 it enters the number into the label.But I want to use keyboard instead of mouse.When i set the forms key preview property to true and use the code below everything works well but when you use the arrow keys it moves the selected button and then when i press enter it press the button which is selected.

**Criteria's of this problems:**

1)It is not possible to use a text-box instead of label.

**One of these solutions can help me...**

1)Disabling the enter key completely.It should be as if a dead key on the keyboard.

2)Disabling the program to select the buttons even when the arrow key is moved.

3)Programming in such a way that It should click the equals button only when i press the enter key.

Please help me to get rid of this problem. And thanks in advance.

The code i have used is:

> Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
>   System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
>
> ```
>     If e.KeyChar = "0" Then
>         Btn0.PerformClick()
>     ElseIf e.KeyChar = "1" Then
>         Btn1.PerformClick()
>     ElseIf e.KeyChar = "2" Then
>         Btn2.PerformClick()
>     ElseIf e.KeyChar = "3" Then
>         Btn3.PerformClick()
>     ElseIf e.KeyChar = "4" Then
>         Btn4.PerformClick()
>     ElseIf e.KeyChar = "5" Then
>         Btn5.PerformClick()
>     ElseIf e.KeyChar = "6" Then
>         Btn6.PerformClick()
>     ElseIf e.KeyChar = "7" Then
>         Btn7.PerformClick()
>     ElseIf e.KeyChar = "8" Then
>         Btn8.PerformClick()
>     ElseIf e.KeyChar = "9" Then
>         Btn9.PerformClick()
>     Else
>         'Donothing Just Ignore
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: I can help you with enter. I am unable to solve the rest right now. Enter: `ElseIf e.KeyChar = Chr(13)`

Comment: This catches your directional keys:     Protected Overrides Function ProcessDialogKey(keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function ... From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300977/arrow-key-events-not-arriving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into this problem, and the solution I came up with was quick and simple.
Just move focus to the label after every time a button is pressed!
For instance, do this:

```
Private Sub Btn0_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Do stuff
    Label1.Focus()
End Sub
```

This focuses the label **which means that the button will be *de*-focused which means that it will *not* be clicked when you press enter**. Good luck!

Comment: You're welcome @user3033480! If it answered your question, feel free to upvote and [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. However, only accept if it fully answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
Else
    'Donothing Just Ignore
End If
```

use

```
Else
    e.handled = true
End If
```

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Probably an easier method than mine, however, the button still stays focused, which might not be optimal.